# Android permission at runtime with external class

Tags: android-permissions

I apologize for my English.

I try for a few hours to create a class that allows a request for permission to run time. I think the basic system makes the code unreadable if you have permission requested in several different activity.

So I created the following class

```
public class PermissionsHelper {

    public interface PermissionHelperListener{
        void accepted();

        void rejected();
    }

    private static  PermissionsHelper mInstance;
    private static  AppCompatActivity mContext;
    public static  ArrayList<PermissionHelperListener> permissionHelperListeners;

    public static PermissionsHelper getInstance(AppCompatActivity context){
        mContext = context;
        if(mInstance == null){
            mInstance = new PermissionsHelper();
        }
        return mInstance;
    }

    public void requestPermissions(String perm, PermissionHelperListener permissionHelperListener){
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (mContext.checkSelfPermission(perm) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                int index = permissionHelperListeners.size();
                permissionHelperListeners.add(permissionHelperListener);
                mContext.requestPermissions(new String[]{perm}, index);
            }
        }
    }

    public void requestPermissions (String[] perms, PermissionHelperListener permissionHelperListener){
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            int index = permissionHelperListeners.size();
            permissionHelperListeners.add(permissionHelperListener);
            mContext.requestPermissions(perms, index);
        }
    }

    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            permissionHelperListeners.get(requestCode).accepted();
        } else {
            permissionHelperListeners.get(requestCode).rejected();
        }
        permissionHelperListeners.remove(requestCode);
    }

}
```

I call my class in `onRequestPermissionsResult`like this

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    PermissionsHelper.getInstance(this).onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
}
```

everything is right until now. but when I use `requestPermissions` in my activity there is always the warning to check permission. I used `@SuppressWarnings("ALL")` and it work but I do not really like it. is there an other way to remove this warning or ask permissions with a callback like this ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: no one has any idea for my problem?

Comment: maybe this post might help? https://medium.com/@ali.muzaffar/use-headless-fragment-for-android-m-run-time-permissions-and-to-check-network-connectivity-b48615f6272d#.7sbjr1xjh

Answer (score 0):

Updated:

I've found an awesome solution for this.

Just rename the method that you are using to check the permissions in your helper class to 'checkSelfPermission'. I'm guessing Lint scans the code for these words to decide when to show that dreaded red underline.

Older Answer:

Another way would be to use a try and catch block with a security exception.

```
try {
    //code with the warning goes here
} catch (SecurityException e){
    //do nothing here or ask for permission and recall this method
    //again if the user grants the permission
}
```